Laravel Reverb in Azure Static Web App Web Connection Failed
Websocket connection to wss://sample-api.azurewebsites.net:8081/app/fs213123111 failed
I've been trying to configure Websocket connection from frontend (VUE) Azure Static Web App to backend (Laravel) in Azure Web App Service. It's working fine locally but not in the production server.
So far I've installed the necessary packages in the front including echo.js.
This is my .env in the front
VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="1fsa12561231245"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="sample-api.azurewebsites.net"
VITE_REVERB_PORT=8080
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="https"

.env in the backend
REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080

REVERB_APP_ID=112345
REVERB_APP_KEY=1fsa12561231245
REVERB_APP_SECRET=adz1dgaghte
REVERB_HOST="sample-api.azurewebsites.net"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=https
REVERB_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

I've also allowed my front end domain in the CORS settings of my App Service but still having the same issue. App service runs in Linux so Websocket is on by default.
Are they any configurations to allow websocket connection in Azure? Thank you!

Web Sockets are supported on Linux apps. The webSocketsEnabled ARM setting does not apply to Linux apps since Web Sockets are always enabled for Linux.

If possible, could you share your backend and frontend code from the above question in text format? Additionally, if possible, please provide the Git repository link as well.

The below are steps to configure WebSocket communication for both the frontend (Vue.js) and backend (Laravel) in an Azure environment.
Install the Laravel WebSockets and  cors packages:
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets


Publish the Laravel WebSockets configuration file:
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\\LaravelWebSockets\\WebSocketsServiceProvider" --tag="config"

Edit config/websockets.php to set up your WebSocket server:
return [
    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('YourPUSHERAPPID'),
            'name' => env('YourAPPNAME'),
            'key' => env('YourPUSHERAPPKEY'),
            'secret' => env('YourPUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('YourPUSHERAPPPATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
        ],
    ],

    'dashboard' => [
        'username' => env('WEBSOCKETSDASHBOARDYourUSERNAME'),
        'password' => env('WEBSOCKETSDASHBOARDYourPASSWORD'),
    ],

    'ratchet' => [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => env('LARAVELWEBSOCKETSYourPORT', 6001),
    ],

    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_YourLOCAL_CERT', null),
        'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_YourLOCAL_PK', null),
        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_YourPASSPHRASE', null),
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
];


Make sure to add  Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) from all domains in your Laravel application, configure the cors.php file to allow requests from any origin.

config/cors.php:
Edit the config/cors.php file:
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*'],  
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'], 
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],  
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],  
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'], 
    'exposed_headers' => [], 
    'max_age' => 0, 
    'supports_credentials' => false,  
];

Register CORS Middleware:
protected $middleware = [
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    // Other middlewares...
];



I followed this link for building real-time applications with Laravel WebSockets.

Event Class for Public Channel:
// app/Events/NewMessage.php
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets;

    public $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('public-chat');
    }
}


use App\Events\NewMessage;
use App\Events\NewChatMessage;


broadcast(new NewMessage('Hello, world!'));


broadcast(new NewChatMessage(1, 'Test Message'))->toOthers();


I used sample code below:


class TimeServer implements MessageComponentInterface {
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Send initial message
        $conn->send("The time is: ");
        
        // Send time every second
        $conn->timeInterval = setInterval(function() use ($conn) {
            $time = date("H:i:s");
            $conn->send("The time is: " . $time);
        }, 1000);
    }



I followed this SO to deploy to an Azure Web App.

Output with Vue in local:


I followed this  so to deploy React Vite on azure server static web app with GitHub.


